# Book where the main character gets stuck in a VR world after going onstage to play it

Tags: story-identification, books

The part I remember was when the main character goes into a big hall I think, where a game is getting released. And because of some other reasons I cannot remember he gets called onto stage to play it. It's like a VR game and he sort of gets stuck in it, with a few other people. And he has to survive in that to live in the real world. I might have read this on a kindle or as a paperback. As far as I know it's available as both.

I really don't remember any other parts of the story, and I'm not very sure whatever I said was what exactly happened. But I think that's a part of the story.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into the question itself. Instead you should post it as an answer to your own question! I have done so for now just to preserve the answer. However, if you want to post the answer yourself please do so and I'll delete mine!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As confirmed by an edit to the question this is the fourth book in the *Alex Rider* series: [*Eagle Strike*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/175004.Eagle_Strike) (2003) by Anthony Horowitz.

> Sir Damian Cray is a philanthropist, peace activist, and the world's most famous pop star. But still it's not enough. He needs more if he is to save the world. Trouble is, only Alex Rider recognizes that it's the world that needs saving from Sir Damian Cray. Underneath the luster of glamour and fame lies a twisted mind, ready to sacrifice the world for his beliefs. But in the past, Alex has always had the backing of the government. This time, he's on his own. Can one teenager convince the world that the most popular man on earth is a madman bent on destruction-before time runs out?